# Convert OctalString (OS2IP) to Integer and viceversa (Integer to Octal String I2OSP) Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, type-conversion, rsa

I'm new in Objective-C and I'm having a few problems developing my code.

I'm implementing RSA algorithm in Objective-C following this paper: http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~calazans/graduate/TPVLSI_I/RSA-oaep_spec.pdf

At this moment I'm trying to convert a non-negative integer into octet String (I2OSP) and its complementary operation, a octet String into a Integer (OS2IP).

I've been able to get a kind of ItOSP function, but it hasn't the correct behaviour. This is what I have right now:

```
-(void) ItoOSP:(int) i buffer:(char []) buffer{
    OSStatus status = errSecSuccess;
    if(i>=256){
        status=errSecParam;
        NSLog(@"Integer too long");
    }

    buffer[0] = (unsigned char)((i >> 24) & 255);
    buffer[1] = (unsigned char)((i >> 16) & 255);
    buffer[2] = (unsigned char)((i >> 8)) & 255;
    buffer[3] = (unsigned char)(i & 255);
}
```

Could you provide me any hint to help me to achieve it please?

I'm stuck in this hole and I can't move with the algorithm without it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:

The input and output of the methods are :

OS2IP(X)
Input: X octet string to be converted
Output: x corresponding nonnegative integer

I2OSP(x, l)
Input: x nonnegative integer to be converted
l intended length of the resulting octet string
Output: X corresponding octet string of length l

In the paper I've mentioned it appears the pseudo code to implement both of them, but as I said I'm rookie programming in objective-c (and C) and I'm not able to develop it.

Comment: It would help if you show your input data and the actual and expected output. And note that "octal" != "octet".

Comment: In the OS2IP the input is an Octet String and I need to transform it in a integer value.  In the I2OSP I have to do the opposite, transform a Integer in a octet string of length L